# Error #1006: value isn to a function

Tags: actionscript-3

I've tried looking this up and can't seem to see why the below is giving me the error above. Closest I came was here: [strange Error 1006: %function_name% is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616770/strange-error-1006-function-name-is-not-a-function) but it doesn't really apply since the below is in my main timeline, frame 1. Should I move it to a "Main.as" class instead?

```
function centerContent(refItem:Object, xOffset:int, yOffset:int) {
    this.x = (refItem.width - this.width)/2 + refItem.x + xOffset;
    this.y = (refItem.height - this.height)/2 + refItem.y + yOffset;
}

// center the item in relation to another item
a_mc.centerContent(another_mc, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to prototype a function on to your MovieClip.

To add this function to a MovieClip, you could extend the MovieClip class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Example extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Example()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function centerContent(refItem:DisplayObject, xOffset:int, yOffset:int):void
        {
            this.x = (refItem.width - this.width) / 2 + refItem.x + xOffset;
            this.y = (refItem.height - this.height) / 2 + refItem.y + yOffset;
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can call your `centerContent` function:

```
var a_mc:Example = new Example();
a_mc.centerContent(obj, 0, 0);
```

Otherwise, you could just pass any `DisplayObject` to the function, as in:

```
public function centerContent(object:DisplayObject, refItem:DisplayObject, xOffset:int, yOffset:int):void
{
    object.x = (refItem.width - object.width) / 2 + refItem.x + xOffset;
    object.y = (refItem.height - object.height) / 2 + refItem.y + yOffset;
}
```

Which you could then call:

```
centerContent(a_mc, obj, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This actually answered my question better than above, though it led me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are confused about how scope works.

Basically, `centerContent` is a part of a class and you are trying to call it from a child of that class. It does not work like that. To call the function, it must be called from the class it is a child of (a function is an object, the same as a MovieClip or Sprite or String is).

So, look at it this way:

```
-Main
--Class1
---another_mc
---a_mc
----function1
----function2
---centerContent()
----refItem
----xOffset
----yOffset
```

You can call an object (again, a function is an object) from its parent and nothing else. So in that image, from a_mc, you can call function1 and function2 (`a_mc.function1()` and `a_mc.function2()`), but not centerContent (`a_mc.centerContent`) because it does not exist within a_mc, but within Class1. So you can call `Class1.centerContent()` (use `this.centerContent()` for proper syntax and scope) or `Class1.a_mc` but not a_mc.centerContent().

Comment: I changed it to be: 'function centerContent(refItem:Object, movingItem:Object, xOffset:int, yOffset:int)...' Thanks!

Comment: Yep. That would be the proper way to handle this. And in your function, swap your reference to `this` with `movingItem` (assuming I am reading your code right). `this` refers to the parent class, but not what you actually want to move.